# How do I transfer music To a Moto4g phone without using Google Play?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

When I try to transfer music files a pop up box appears warning me that the files will be transferred but I might be unable to ply them which happens.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please [edit] your question and include how you are transfering the files (step-by-step), so we can see what goes wrong. I never used "Google Play" to transfer music files (no idea why I should go that way, and even don't know how that should work), but simply copy them to my devices.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you get the default message Windows gives when you try to copy some files and it thinks your phone probably "wont" be able to play them.

Just select the "Ignore" option and go on copying anyways, the phone should be able to play the music fine.